# Java-8 lambda expression equivalent for traditional for

Tags: java, for-loop, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I have a `for` statement in Java 7 and it's work fine:

```
Double totalDistributedCredit = 0D;
Set<DistributionPlan> distributionPlanList = loadByEntityId(creditResourceId).getDistributionPlan();
for (DistributionPlan distributionPlan : distributionPlanList) {
    Set<DistributedCredit> distributedCreditList = iDistributionPlanService.loadByEntityId(distributionPlan.getId()).getDistributedCredit();
    for (DistributedCredit distributedCredit : distributedCreditList) {
        totalDistributedCredit += distributedCredit.getDistributedAmount();
    }
}
```

I want to convert my code to Stream & collect in Java 8 and **return a double value**.

Comment: And what have you tried so far? SO is not a translation service.

Comment: Thank you very much for the comments that you made. But I tried, but did not receive an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following should work:

```
double sum = distributionPlanList.stream()
    .flatMap(e -> iDistributionPlanService.loadByEntityId(e.getId()).getDistributedCredit().stream())
    .map(dc -> dc.getDistributedAmount())
    .mapToDouble(Double::doubleValue)
    .sum();
```

Comment: .flatMap(e -> iDistributionPlanService.loadByEntityId(e.getId()).getDistributedCredit())     
error : Type mismatch: cannot convert from Set<DistributedCredit> to Stream<? extends Object>

Comment: Updated the answer, try now?

Comment: Thank you very much for your dear friend, was absolutely correct.

Comment: You can mark the answer as correct if it has helped you.

Comment: @DarshanMehta `map` and `mapToDouble` can be merged to `mapToDouble(DistributedCredit::getDistributedAmount)`.